# How to flush .NET SerialPort?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port, flush

I am using an object based on the .NET SerialPort class in a VB.NET program I am creating.  I have problems when performing the following:

1. Send data to the serial port
2. Close the port
3. Close the application
4. Reopen the port

What happens is that leftover data gets sent out even though I have closed the port and the application.  The DiscardOutBuffer() method doesn't seem to help either.

What is the best way to flush out the buffer after use so that there is nothing left in it once the port is closed?

Comment: Are you writing strings or bytes?  If you are writing strings try flushing using the basestream property.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: I am writing out strings.

Comment: Have you tried using the Flush() method?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/jj652595(v=vs.102)